# subsection 'Difference equation' in Strang's linear algebra section 6.3

Tags: linear-algebra

In this section, Strang converts the constant-coefficient differential equation into linear algebra in order to solve them. I was in trouble reading the difference equation in this section which demands to provide an alternative solution to Example 3 which is a second differential equation of the motion around a circle.

Here is Example 3:

Motion around a circle with $y'' + y = 0$ and $y = \cos{t}$.

And I have no problem to solve this by applying the usual method that converts the equation into linear algebra. However, I can't understand the following that applying the difference equation and converts it to linear algebra for solving the same example. Here is the description:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't understand this entire section perhaps it is because I have never studied the difference equation before but I really want to understand this part because it looks important. Therefore I wonder if anyone can provide me a clear explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should be more explicit : indicate the first line where you are lost.

Comment: Hints: Difference equations are employed to compute derivatives. The method requires knowing previous solutions to compute the following step (Eq 12). The subindices  $n$, $n-1$ and $n+1$ stand for the steps of the "discretized" solution at the states $n$, the one that precedes it and the one that follows respectively (you may, loosely speaking, associate each $n$ to the Id of each point in the last figure). We cannot feed infinite or infinitely small to a computer. Hence, we use time increment $\Delta t$ as an auxiliary element to compute the trajectory.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think I was lost from the beginning when it says that the three difference methods don't complete the perfect circle in 32 time steps of length $\Delta{t} = 2\pi /32$ in which case I don't know where the 32 comes from.

Comment: @Basco Ok I see, so take the forward choice for example, the spiral is going to be closer and closer to the perfect circle when more and more steps are taken (in this case, 32). And my second equation is about how he obtains the equation (12) from the formula above.

Comment: If you are OK with Eq. 11F (where the solution at $n+1$ is obtained from the previous one  at $n$ and a time increment, then you will notice that $U_{n+1}$ is a vector containing the variables on the LHS of Eq 11F and $U_n=(Y_n \ Z_n)^T$. The matrix are just the values multiplying $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ on the RHS of Eq 11.

Comment: @Basco Do you mind to tell me why from the eq 11 to eq 12 the variable $Y_{n-1}$ is gone and how the $Z_n$ appears. Because in my thought reorganize the eq 11, 11F will give me $Y_{n+1} = 2Y_{n} - Y_{n-1} - (\Delta{t})^2 Y_{n-1}$ ? Or in another word how $Z_n$ is defined in this case ?

Comment: Sure. The first equation stands for a second derivative. You can get a first derivative from Eq. 12 operating algebraically (just try to get $Z_n$ from the first expression in Eq. 11 F)

Comment: @Basco Can you give me more hints on how to conduct the term $Z_n$ from the first expression in eq 11. 11F. And also why the term $Y_{n-1}$ is eliminated.

Comment: @Basco So according to the eq 11. 11C I can algebraically obtain that $\frac{Y_n - Y_{n-1}}{\Delta{t}}$ is $Z_n$. However, it contradicts to the first equation in eq 12  that $\frac{Y_{n+1} - Y_n}{\Delta{t}}$ is $Z_n$.

Comment: Notice that $Z$ is equivalent (in some sense) to $y'$ not $y''$, see my solution below.

Comment: About the $32$ steps : it is an arbitrary power of 2 (taking a power of 2 simplifies many operations).

Answer (score 2):

The author is using finite differences to explain its usefulness and limitations by leveraging on the concepts described previously. The example is still $y''+y=0$ which was re-written as $y''=-y$ in the first paragraph of the section titled "Difference Equations".

The value of $y''$ is approximated by numerically by the Eq. 11 (FCB). Then there is a renaming of variables $Z$ stands for the discretized first derivative (not the second) of the solution, while $Y$ is the discretized solution (this is no different from the vector $\textbf{u}$ in Eq. 10 -and I mention the vector, not the equation as a whole).

The author abandon the 2nd derivative in favor of the phase portrait diagram that contains $u=(y,y')$, see Fig. 6.3. as a qualitative representation of the solution space of the ODE. Then, he  uses the forward scheme to determine $Z$ and $Y$ at the time step $n+1$ knowing the solution at the step $n$ in an incremental fashion in Eq. 11 F (which can be obtain from Taylor expansion by getting rid of higher order terms). Eq. 12 contains the same information as Eq. 11 in matrix form where $U_n=(Y_n \: Z_n)^T$, the vector on the LHS stands for the homologous vector $U_{n+1}$ and the matrix contains the coefficients multiplying $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ on the RHS of Eq. 11F.

The construction of the diagrams is essentially analogous to an integration where the pair $(Y_n,Z_n)$ denotes the point $n$ in the phase portrait (See figures 6.3 and 6.4) The author also claims that there are numerical errors that produce inaccurate results (ideally all points should lie in a circle) for a fixed steplength equivalent to 32 pts along the perimeter of the circle. The errors are reduced if the number of points are increased.

Comment: Thank you for answering most of my confusion and there is just one more problem that annoys me that is how the author deduces the eq 12 from the forward scheme of the eq 11. I see the $Z_n$ is equivalent to $y'$ and $y''$ in some sense.

Comment: He does not seems to be deducing/deriving them. It is more like he is reminding us of the finite difference schemes. They may have been presented earlier in the book (or in an appendix) or, as typical in courses given in sequences, it may be a concept from a previous class. The keywords if you want to know more is "finite differences".

Comment: I see what you are saying and I don't think he presents any finite difference schemes prior to this section, it was just like came up suddenly and ended so quickly that I was in confuse throughout these two pages.

Comment: But knowing more finite difference is definitely helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is how they derived the relation between matrices $U_{n+1}$ and $U_n$ 
First Consider Finite difference stencil for the first derivative $$y^{'}_{n} = \frac{y_{n+1} - y_{n}}{\Delta t}$$
$$y_{n+1} = y^{'}_{n}(\Delta t) + y_{n}$$
Therefore the matrix currently looks like this (Note I have relabelled Z as $y^{'}$)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{n+1}\\
y^{'}_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \Delta t\\
  & 
\end{pmatrix}
.
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{n}\\
y^{'}_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now moving to the second differential equation
$$y^{"}_{n} = -y_{n} = \frac{y^{'}_{n+1} - y^{'}_{n}}{\Delta t}$$
$$y^{'}_{n+1} = y^{'}_{n} - y_{n}\Delta t$$
The final matrix now looks like this
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{n+1}\\
y^{'}_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \Delta t\\
-\Delta t & 1
\end{pmatrix}
.
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{n}\\
y^{'}_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$